# Display an evenly-spaced sample of rows from a data frame in R

Tags: r

Instead of looking at the first `n` rows of a data frame, as `head(mydf)` does, or the last `n` as `tail(mydf)` does, it occurs to me that I would often rather see `n` evenly-spaced rows, including the first and the last row. For example, if a data frame had 601 rows, this hypothetical function would display row 1, 101, 201, 301, 401, 501, and 601, assuming that 6 is the default number, as it is for `head()` and `tail()`.

Is there a built-in function of some package that does this, and if not what would be the best way to implement?

For example, for the data frame `mydf <- data.frame(name=letters, value=101:126)`, I would want the output of an alternative to `head()` called `myview()` to be something like:

```
> myview(mydf)
   name value
1     a   101
6     f   106
11    k   111
16    p   116
21    u   121
26    z   126
```

Comment: OK, will do....

Answer (score 2):

You can directly do this in `seq` :

```
looksee <- function(df, n = 6) df[seq(1, nrow(df), length.out = n),]

looksee(mydf)
#   name value
#1     a   101
#6     f   106
#11    k   111
#16    p   116
#21    u   121
#26    z   126

looksee(mydf, 10)
#   name value
#1     a   101
#3     c   103
#6     f   106
#9     i   109
#12    l   112
#14    n   114
#17    q   117
#20    t   120
#23    w   123
#26    z   126
```

Comment: Nice, thanks, this is far simpler. I just assumed you can't do something like df[4.5, ] but it rounds

Answer (score 1):

This is my try at implementing, but it is probably not very robust compared to `head()`--it will only work for things that `nrow()` works for, for one thing.

```
looksee <- function(df, n=6){
  q <- seq(0, 1, length.out=n)
  n = nrow(df)
  rows <- round(quantile(1:n, probs=q))
  return(df[rows,])
}
```

Example usage:

```
> mydf <- data.frame(name=letters, value=101:126)
> looksee(mydf)
   name value
1     a   101
6     f   106
11    k   111
16    p   116
21    u   121
26    z   126
```

Comment: You could change `nrow` to `NROW` and then change your `return` to something like `return(if (is.null(dim(df))) df[rows] else df[rows, ])`.